# how to create a table with a fixed first column and row?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a table with a fixed first column and row. I tried to implement it like the scheme below (it's a vertical UIScrollView with a horizontal UIScrollView inside). The problem is that I need to make them move together if I drag my finger across the screen diagonally with the acceleration and bouncing animations. I already tried creating a view on top, getting the movement with touchesBegan: and touchesMoved: and changing the contentOffset programatically but it has laggy and without acceleration and bounce. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

scheme:
[image]

Comment: You could use Android

Answer (score 0):

From the first look:

Parent View: ScrollView with vertical Scroll only.

Inside:

- First Row: UICollectionView (with horizontal scroll)
- First Column: Normal UIView (or table view or colleciton view - depends on your setup)
- The rest of cells: UICollectionView with horizontal scroll

Comment: the first column must be fixed, the others must go like under. already tried with collection view and table views inside, the problem comes when you scroll anywhere in this big table it has to scroll in all the cells including the first fixed one if you scroll vertically or diagonally

Comment: Let me clarify: first row and collumn are both fixed? Or just first collumn?

Comment: first row and column are both fixed

Answer (score 0):

Add an array value at the index path 0 manually. So that you will get a cell value constantly.